# array gets lost while rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MYProfile.js file which works fine. I have removed the imports and styles section.

```js
class MyProfile extends Component {
  constructor({match}) {
    console.log("constructor");
    super()
    this.state = {
      user: '',
      redirectToSignin: false
    };
    this.match = match;
  }

  init = (userId) => {
    console.log("init");
    const jwt = auth.isAuthenticated();
    read({
      userId: userId
    }, {t: jwt.token}).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        this.setState({redirectToSignin: true})
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({user: data});
        console.log(this.state.user.roles);
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps = (props) => {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps");
    this.init(props.match.params.userId)
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    this.init(this.match.params.userId)
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    const {classes} = this.props;
    const redirectToSignin = this.state.redirectToSignin;
    if (redirectToSignin) { return <Redirect to='/signin'/> }
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={4}>
        <Typography type="title" className={classes.title}>
          Profile
        </Typography>
        <List dense>
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Avatar>
                <Person/>
              </Avatar>
            </ListItemAvatar>
            <ListItemText primary={this.state.user.name} secondary={this.state.user.email} /> 
          </ListItem>
          <Divider/>
          <ListItem>
            <Typography>Your Profile ID: {this.state.user._id}</Typography>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            <Typography>You are assigned the following Roles: </Typography>
          </ListItem>
          <Divider/>
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemText primary={"Joined: " + (
              new Date(this.state.user.created)).toDateString()}/>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Paper>
    )
  }
}

MyProfile.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyProfile)
```

I get the following output on console

```js
MyProfile.js?dec7:33 constructor
MyProfile.js?dec7:69 render
MyProfile.js?dec7:64 componentDidMount
MyProfile.js?dec7:43 init
MyProfile.js?dec7:51 {status: "New", roles: Array(3), created: "2018-09-20T16:14:58.110Z", _id: "5ba3c7829708249ed4c3ce5b", name: "avinash", …}
MyProfile.js?dec7:69 render
MyProfile.js?dec7:53 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

the roles show me:

```js
  (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {Module: "Core", Role: "Owner"}
  1: {Module: "Core", Role: "Administrator"}
  2: {Module: "Core", Role: "Regular User"}
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Now I plan to render the roles, so the user can see what roles are assigned to him. So, I add this block of code in the render section just before the last

```js
  <ListItem>
    <Typography>You are assigned the following Roles: </Typography>
  </ListItem>
  {
    this.state.user.roles.map((item, i)=>{
      console.log(item);
      <ListItem key={i}>{item.Module}-{item.Role}</ListItem>
    })
  }
  <Divider/>
```

and I am getting this error:

```js
MyProfile.js?dec7:33 constructor
MyProfile.js?dec7:69 render
MyProfile.js?dec7:33 constructor
MyProfile.js?dec7:69 render
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at ProxyComponent.render (MyProfile.js?dec7:95)
    at ProxyComponent.hotComponentRender (react-hot-loader.development.js?c2cb:578)
    at ProxyComponent.proxiedRender (react-hot-loader.development.js?c2cb:586)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:8389)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:8357)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:8982)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11814)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11843)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11874)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?61bb:12449)
```

I tried to find the type of the variable by using typeof(this.state.user.roles) it said - Object. Googled it and found it was appropriate. I tried to cast it to array so that I can use the map, but failed. 
I am sure that the roles state variable is Array, but it get undefined as soon as it enters the render-return().

Am I missing something? Please help... already spent the whole weekend on this. :(

Thanks a lot for helping in anticipation.

Comment: did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, when your component will mount, `this.state.user` is a string not an object so there’s no roles inside.

Roles is not defined initially, so there’s no map available for that undefined variable and of course no iteration occur at all...

So you should define it as an empty array to prevent the error.

```js
constructor({match}) {
    console.log("constructor");
    super()
    this.state = {
      user: {roles:[]},
      redirectToSignin: false
    };
    this.match = match;
  }
```

Additionally / alternatively, you can make sure that roles is not undefined before iterating.

```js
{
    this.state.user.roles && this.state.user.roles.map((item, i)=>{
      console.log(item);
      <ListItem key={i}>{item.Module}-{item.Role}</ListItem>
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... all these tricks come from experience :) Great Job. Thanks  a lot.